# Converting a List[Try[A]] to List[A] in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I want to filter out bad input from input data. I'm currently using `scala.util.Try` to wrap any exceptions. Following is a simple example where 3I throws a `NumberFormatException`. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this in Scala ?

```
val data = List ( ("Joe", "20"), ("James", "30"), ("Pete", "3I") )

scala> val parsedData = data.map{ d => Try{Person( d._1, d._2.toInt ) }}
parsedData: List[scala.util.Try[Person]] = List(Success(Person(Joe,20)), Success(Person(James,30)), Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3I"))

scala> val validdata = parsedData.map{ x => x match {
     | case Success(s) => Some(s)
     | case Failure(f) => None }
     | }
validdata: List[Option[Person]] = List(Some(Person(Joe,20)), Some(Person(James,30)), None)

scala> validdata.flatten
res13: List[Person] = List(Person(Joe,20), Person(James,30))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `collect` to keep only the values that match the pattern you desire:

```
parsedData collect { case Success(x) => x }
```

This will also work, though I don't think it's quite as clear:

```
parsedData.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there is a better way of handling the `Try` part ?

Comment: A better way to do what, exactly? I don't see anything wrong with the way you're using it, if all you want is to discard the failures.

Comment: Yeah a better way to discard failures.

Comment: I think he means that he wants to execute some process with discarding failures, like logging or some sorts

Answer (score 0):

One approach that bypasses the use of `Try`, as follows,

```
for ( d <- data if d._2.forall(_.isDigit) ) yield Person(d._1, d._2.toInt)
```

Yet this may not prove as scalable as @m-z approach.