# Convert Iterable[Try[U]] to Try[Iterable[U]] in Scala

Tags: scala

**How can an `Iterable` of `Try` values be converted into a Try of Iterable?**  If the Iterable contains a failure then the first Failure should be returned, if there are no failures then an Iterable of the `Success` values should be returned.

As an example, assume the conversion function is called `squash`:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def squash[U](iterable : Iterable[Try[U]]) : Try[Iterable[U]] = ???
```

The expected behavior for an Iterable containing failures:

```
val containsFailure : Iterable[Try[Int]] = 
  Iterable[Try[Int]](Success(42), Failure(new Exception("foo")), Success(43), Failure(new Exception("bar")))

assert(squash(containsFailure) ==  Failure(new Exception("foo")))
```

And the expected behavior for an Iterable with no failures:

```
val noFailures : Iterable[Try[Int]] = 
  Iterable[Try[Int]](Success(42), Success(43), Success(44))

assert(squash(noFailures) == Success(Iterable(42,43,44)))
```

I am looking for a solution that only contains standard scala functionality, please don't include libraries such as `scalaz` or `cats` as part of the answer.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Are you open to using external libraries and / or to change your types?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No external libraries, scala native functionality only.  I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, and are you open to using something that is not an **Iterable**?  Technically speaking an **Iterable** doesn't even guarantee order.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah, yes that does make sense.  But it should be kept "generic" if possible, e.g. `Traversable` instead of `Array` or `List`.

Comment: When you say generic is because you want to preserve the collection type? Like if I pass a **List** return a **List**? - Most of the _"abstract"_ collections of the stdlib are there just for code reuse not really for end users, most of them are pretty useless IMHO and many _(like me)_ argue the stdlib could be simplified a lot but that is another discussion.

Comment: No, not necessarily for type preservation.  Just to keep the resulting type independent of underlying implementation details.

Comment: [List\[Try\[T\]\] to Try\[List\[T\]\] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57516234/2359227)

Comment: [Converting a List\[Try\[A\]\] to List\[A\] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27955294/2359227)

Comment: Here are a couple of alternatives: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/CD9okV0fTBeKmt3JV6DnSQ/14 - BTW, while I agree it is not good to include something like **cats** for just one function, at one point one has to consider how many things are you reimplementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping with the profile as posted in the question.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def squash[U](iterable : Iterable[Try[U]]) : Try[Iterable[U]] =
  iterable.foldLeft(Try(Iterable.empty[U])){
    case (Success(a),Success(b)) => Success(a ++ Iterable(b))
    case (Success(_),Failure(ex)) => Failure(ex)
    case (failed, _) => failed
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that returns a `Seq` instead of an `Iterable`:

```
def squash[U](iterable : Iterable[Try[U]]): Try[Seq[U]] =
  iterable.foldLeft[Try[Vector[U]]](Success(Vector.empty[U]))((result: Try[Vector[U]], t: Try[U]) =>
    result flatMap (vector => t match {
      case Failure(ex) => Failure[Vector[U]](ex)
      case Success(value) => Success(vector :+ value)
    }))
```